# moment.js Timezone Parsing and Comparison

Tags: momentjs

I'm receiving timestamps in the following format `'2016-08-17T14:00:00-04:00'`, which I can parse in moment with `moment('2016-08-17T14:00:00-04:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ')`.

But the problem is that I want to print out `.format('LLLL')` and have it read `Wednesday, August 17, 2016 10:00 AM`, i.e. subtracting `-04:00` from `14:00:00` (NY from UTC). It appears that there is a `_tzm: -240` property in the moment object that looks like it holds that -4 hours value, but how do I use that property?

The other goal is to be able to pass in the current time and test if it is between the `startDate` and `endDate` variables below. I am guessing if I can convert both to NY-EST I can do this, but I can't seem to get moment to accept the timezone parameter.

Any thoughts?

```
var moment = require('moment');

// Timestamp strings from API
var startDate = '2016-08-17T14:00:00-04:00';
var endDate = '2016-08-17T15:00:00-04:00';

// Create a range from the start and end dates
var range = moment().range(new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));

// Get the current time
var currentTime = new Date();

// Does the current time fall within the range b/w the start and end dates
range.contains(currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found is below. Adding the value from `momentObj._tzm` to the parsed date.

```
module.exports.convertDateToProperTimezone = function (dt) {
    var _m = moment(dt, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
    return _m.add(_m._tzm, 'minutes');
};
```